# XSLT Get the first occurrence of a specific tag

Tags: xslt

Let's say i have a full html-document as XML-input. 
How would the XSLT-file look if i only want to output the first (or any) image from the html?

Comment: What have you gotten so far? What is not working?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for the only correct solution so far. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One XPath expression that selects the first `<img>` element in a document is:

**`(//img)[1]`**

**Do note** that **a frequent mistake -- as made by `@Oded` in his answer** is to suggest the following XPath expression -- in general it may select more than one element:

**`//img[1]`**           (: WRONG !!! :)

This selects all `<img>` elements in the document, each one of which is the first `<img>` child of its parent.

Here is the exact explanation of this frequent mistake -- in the [W3C XPath 1.0 Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev):

**NOTE**: The location path `//para[1]` does not mean the same as the location path `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first descendant `para` element; the former selects all descendant `para` elements that are the first para children of their parents.

**A further problem** exists if the document has defined a default namespace, which must be the case with XHTML. XPath treats any unprefixed name as belonging to *no namespace* and the expression `(//img)[1]` selects no node, because there is no element in the document that belongs to *no namespace* and has name `img`.

In this case there are two ways to specify the wanted XPath expression:

1. `(//x:img)[1]`  -- where the prefix `x` is associated (by the hosting language) with the specific default namespcae (in this case this is the *XHTML namespace*).
2. `(//*[name()='img'])[1]`

Comment: thank you, I've spent hour(s) trying to find out what is wrong my query.

Answer (score 2):

The [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) expression the will retrieve the first image from an HTML page: `(//img)[1]`.

See the answer from `@Dimitre Novatchev` for more information on problems with it.

Comment: See my answer for an explanation of the issue with your answer. Read the XPath spec -- the definition of the `//` abbreviation, and search for this frequent mistake. If the problem is still not clear, ask a separate question and many people will be glad to explain. :)

Comment: I definitely don't want to read the XPath spec. But I see what Dimitre is saying. The `//img[1]` will select the first img tag of *any* parent rather than the first of the document.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev - thanks for the correction. Answer updated.